# Two actions to call a script Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, onclick, onchange

I have a function to call a PHP script using Ajax, I would to add another event to call the same PHP page, how can I add it instead of repeating the same Ajax call?

```
$('.episodeNum').change(function(){
    var formItems = $('form.addMedia').serialize();
    var dataString = formItems;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "grabMedia.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
```

I would to add a click function to call the same script:

```
$('.clickButton').click(function(){
    var formItems = $('form.addMedia').serialize();
    var dataString = formItems;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "grabMedia.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
```

How can I combine both of them??

Thanks for your usual help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function of the code can be made and it can be called on both the events:

```
function post_data()
{
    var formItems = $('form.addMedia').serialize();
    var dataString = formItems;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "grabMedia.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { }
}

$('.episodeNum').change(function(){
    post_data();
});

$('.clickButton').click(function(){
    post_data();
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `$('.episodeNum').change(post_data);` and `$('.clickButton').click(post_data);`

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit your need?

```
var post_data = function()
{
    var formItems = $('form.addMedia').serialize();
    var dataString = formItems;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "grabMedia.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { }
};

$('.episodeNum').change(post_data);

$('.clickButton').click(post_data);
```